# Undefined offset

Tags: php, mysql

Supuestamente el contador finaliza en **"2"** pero el error me marca que no esta definido **"3"**.

```
<?php include_once 'includes/templates/header.php'; ?>


 <section class="seccion contenedor">
    <h2>Calendario de Eventos</h2>
            <?php
                    try {
                        require_once('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');
                        $sql = "SELECT `evento_id`, `nombre_evento`, `fecha_evento`, `hora_evento`, `cat_evento`, `nombre_invitado`, `apellido_invitado` ";
          $sql .= "FROM `eventos` ";
          $sql .= "INNER JOIN `categoria_evento` ";
          $sql .= "ON eventos.id_cat_evento = categoria_evento.id_categoria ";
          $sql .= "INNER JOIN `invitados` ";
          $sql .= "ON eventos.id_inv = invitados.invitado_id ";
          $sql .= "ORDER BY `evento_id` ";
                        $resultado = $conn->query($sql);

                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $error = $e->getMessage();
                    }
             ?>
     <div class="calendario">

             <?php while($eventos = $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) { ?>

       <?php $dias = array(); ?>
       <?php foreach($eventos as $evento) {
         $dias[] = $evento['fecha_evento'];
       } ?>

       <?php $dias = array_values(array_unique($dias)) ?>

       <?php $contador = 0; ?>
       <?php foreach($eventos as $evento): ?>

         <?php $dia_actual = $evento['fecha_evento']; ?>
         <?php if($dia_actual == $dias[$contador]): ?>
                <h3>
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <?php echo $evento['fecha_evento']; ?>
                </h3>
                <?php $contador++; ?>
         <?php endif; ?>

         <div class="dia">
           <p class="titulo"><?php echo utf8_encode($evento['nombre_evento']); ?></p>
           <p class="hora"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo $evento['fecha_evento'] . " " . $evento['hora_evento'] . "Hs"; ?></p>
           <p>
                <?php $categoria_evento = $evento['cat_evento']; ?>
                <?php
                    switch ($categoria_evento) {
                      case 'Talleres':
                        echo '<i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i> Talleres';
                        break;
                      case 'Conferencia':
                        echo '<i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i> Conferencia';
                        break;
                      case 'Seminario':
                        echo '<i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i> Seminario';
                        break;
                      default:
                        echo "";
                        break;
                    }
                 ?>
           </p>
           <p><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <?php echo $evento['nombre_invitado'] . " " . $evento['apellido_invitado']; ?>
           </p>

         </div>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
       </div><!--.calendario-->

             <?php } ?>


 </section>
```

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in D:\xampp\htdocs\gdlwebcamp\calendario.php on line 37

Comment: Que no está definido "3" dónde? Indica el error que te marca. Lo que has puesto en el título sólo es la ruta de tu archivo, no un error.

Comment: Perdon no me di cuenta que me falto escribir la linea completa. Ahi edite en negrita marque el error que me da.

Comment: Cuantos eventos tienes? si tienes mas eventos que días ese error te va a pasar mucho por que tu variable contador seguirá aumentando conforme mas eventos hayan !

Comment: No sé de que trata la lógica de tu código, pero por ejemplo este movimiento me parece sospechoso: `$dias = array_values(array_unique($dias))`. Me parece que manipulas demasiado tu array `$dias` y provocas de esa forma un código no controlado, inconsistente, el cual puede fallar en cualquier momento. En mi opinión particular el hecho de traer datos: `$dias[] = $evento['fecha_evento'];` para luego *desguasarlos*, manipularlos, modificarlos varias veces quitándoles cosas... me parece una mala práctica de programación y de la impresión de que subyace un mal planteamiento en la lógica del programa.

Answer (score 0):

En el `if` tienes `$dias[$contador]` y le estás pasando `$dias[3]`.

Lo que el error indica, es que el array `$dias` no tiene tantos campos, será un array de **tres** registros (`$dias[2]`) y estás intentando acceder a su **cuarto** registro (`$dias[3]`) que no existe.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que el error te viene de esta línea:

```
<?php if($dia_actual == $dias[$contador]): ?>
```

El error te indica que tu array tiene 3 posiciones y estas intentando acceder a una cuarta. Y esto te viene de un error de lógica: **$contador** obtiene su valor al recorrer el array de eventos, y de hecho en tu array de días estas guardando las fechas de los eventos, pero con la línea:

```
<?php $dias = array_values(array_unique($dias)) ?>
```

estas eliminando posiciones de tu array **$dias**, en cuanto se dan dos eventos en un mismo día. Es decir, que antes de esta línea tanto tu array **$dias** como tu array **$eventos** tienen el mismo número de elementos, y hay no tienes el error, pero una vez filtrado **$dias**, como te dije si dos eventos se producen en el mismo día, tienes tu error...

Saludos.